# How can I run javascript like a batch file?

Tags: javascript

How can I run javascript like a batch file?

I want to run the script below at midnight every day.

However, if you do a command in window.location.href, all subsequent JavaScript commands are ignored.

I want to register and run the task scheduler in Windows environment, but is there any possible way?

```
async function init() {
   window.location.href = 'url where I want to go';
     await timer(3000);
}

init().then(e => {

window.alert = function() {};

const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.List > div.board-list > div.list > table > tbody > tr');


const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

async function load() {
for (let list of lists) {
     console.log(list);
    list.querySelector('td.list-btn > a.btn.btn-primary').click();
     await timer(3000);
   }
}
});
```

Best Regards!

Comment: someone else will go on better details .. but in the meantime: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer unless you want a real browser window to open up and launch a static html page like that loaded from local.. in that case it's quite easier

Comment: Cron + `node your_script.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

To control a website, it needs to be loaded by a webbrowser. (for example Puppeteer, like Diego pointed out)
[You can find examples here](https://github.com/checkly/puppeteer-examples).
To execute the code once a day you can either use cron to call your file or use a package like [Node schedule](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-schedule). With the secound solution the file needs to run already